# How to add an image next to picker view entries?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

As illustrated in this picture, I need to add an image next to my picker view entries, it's a picker view that is added to a `UITextfield`, what is needed is adding an image in place of the blue triangle, an image next to each option, how to do this?

### [image]

I found solutions for this in objective-C, but found nothing for swift.

I will pick the first answer as the answer for this question and vote up for any useful comment..

Thanks.

Comment: You want an image attached to each option in the picker, that scrolls along with the item, correct?

Comment: correct, this is already answered, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a picker view you either provide a title for each item, or a custom view for each item. If you want an image combined with text you should provide a custom view.

You need to implement the `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method in your picker's data source. You'll need to provide a view that contains an image view and a label. You can either create that in code or load a new one from an XIB file each time you need to create one. I don't have any ready-made code for you, but this isn't that difficult.